# Double limit in integral

Tags: integration, limits

I need to find the following expression:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{xe^{-bx}}dx$$

When $a$ and $b$ to $\infty$

I've no idea how to start

Comment: are you sure that your integral does converge?

Answer (score 0):

With Laplace properties
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{xe^{-bx}}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{bx}\cos(ax)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{s-b}{(s-b)^2+a^2}ds\to0$$
as $a\to\infty$ and $b\to\infty$.